# Getting 3D coordinates from a 2D image

Tags: python, camera-calibration, coordinate-transformation, normals

I'm looking for a way to get 3D coordinates from a 2D image.
Because I need to find the normal vectors of several surfaces in the 2d image (if there is a way to find normal vectors without 3D coordinates, I'd love to hear about it).

The conditions are as follows:
The 2D image is from a regular camera.
Only one frame is available.
No depth information is available.
Camera calibration is available.
You are using Python (but if you have a way to use another language, please let me know so I can use it as a reference).

Is it possible to get 3D coordinates from a 2D image under the above conditions?

My searching skills don't allow me to find what I'm looking for, all the methods I found require depth information.
So if you know how, please let me know.

I haven't written and run the code, but I've thought about using a depth estimation model(DL)...
But I thought it would be too complicated, so I came to ask if there is a simpler way to do it.

Comment: My guess is that it is not possible as you need (at least) two pictures. While taking the picture, the camera's auto-focus can determine distances to objects, but that information is normally not stored.
But if you can make assumptions about the shapes (e.g. being right angles, etc.) there might be some mathematical tricks that can help.

Comment: Then I'll have to find another way... thank you :)

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77998857/get-normal-vector-of-floor-by-camera-calibration